# wcf reference with nested arrays inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, wsdl

I have to call the method of a thirdy part Wcf service with complex data structure as parameter. With VS2012 I reference the Wsdl. The Reference.cs is auto generated. The parameter is a big structure and there are some nested arrays of custom elements. Following is a part of code into Reference.cs

```
    private ProcessTableMachinery[] processDataTableMachineryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=27)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    public ProcessTableMachinery[] ProcessDataTableMachinery {
        get {
            return this.processDataTableMachineryField;
        }
        set {
            this.processDataTableMachineryField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ProcessDataTableMachinery");
        }
    }
```

ProcessTableMachinery is a class and it contains another array as following one.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://blue-group.it/")]
public partial class ProcessTableMachinery : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private SingleDataMachinery[] dataTableValuesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=7)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    public SingleDataMachinery[] DataTableValues {
        get {
            return this.dataTableValuesField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataTableValuesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DataTableValues");
        }
    }


    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I have to init dataTableValuesField with some data as following.

```
objRetTable.ProcessDataTableMachinery[iIndex].dataTableValuesField = new RemoteWebService.SingleDataMachinery[1];
```

I get an error ProcessTableMachinery.dataTableValuesField is inaccessible due to its protection level. I am looking for a workaround. If I change dataTableValuesField to public into reference.cs I get a runtime reflection error. Should I modify Wsdl or autogenerated class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is when fields are generated from the Wsdl it generates a public property (getter and setter) and a private field. You must use the public property (**DataTableValues**) and not the field (**dataTableValuesField**):

```
objRetTable.ProcessDataTableMachinery[iIndex].DataTableValues = new RemoteWebService.SingleDataMachinery[1];
```